# How to call Web API url via window application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Now I'm creating a sample web API. It has been set up in IIS and can access it via URL. I want to call that url via window application. How can I call that url without browser launch.

Comment: Show some code to show us what you've done so far.

Comment: here is the example code for window application

   Dim url As String = "http://localhost/Window/index.html"
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)


this code is working but I don't want the browser to be launch.

I also try in self hosting web API with below codes. But, It's not working

string url = "http://localhost:60064/api/Values ;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";

Answer (score 1):

Use the aptly-named [`HttpClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient or WSDL, subject to the nature of your web API.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) or HttpClient if you want lower level access.